# Can't make repaint() work

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint, paintcomponent

My class looks like this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painter extends JPanel {
    int x=200;
    int y=200;
    int newX;
    int newY;

    Painter(){
           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    }

    public void moveSquare(int newX, int newY){
           if(newY != y|| newX != x){
                repaint(x,y, 10, 10);
                y = newY;
                x = newX;
                repaint(x,y, 10, 10);
           }        
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
           super.paintComponent(g);
           g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

The methods are called from another class. The values for `x` and `y` do change the way they should. However the square does not move. Have I done something wrong here?

EDIT Yes, I am calling "super". I just deleted it accidentally when I copied and edited the code here. Now edited it back in.

Comment: Well you are on the correct site. Thats for sure.

Comment: Try calling just `repaint()` :-)

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `Canvas`, anyways.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `super.paintComponent(g)` rather than `paintComponent(g)`

in

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

otherwise you will loop indefinitely.

Comment: @user949300 He most likely is experiencing stack overflows on the thread calling paintComponent().

Comment: Yes, I am calling super. I just deleted it accidentally when I copied and edited the code here.

Comment: This works perfectly for me just by calling _moveSquare_. Are you changing either X or Y?

Comment: @Reimeus, the parameters are changed one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `repaint(x, y, w, h)` only sets a select region as dirty; `Graphics` sets a clip around this boundary, and thus you will only see changes occur there. Using `repaint()` without any arguments will mark the entire area as dirty :-)

According to an Oracle article on AWT `paint` (found [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callback)),

> When AWT invokes this method, the `Graphics` object parameter is pre-configured with the appropriate state for drawing on this particular component:
>
> - The Graphics object's *color* is set to the component's `foreground` property.
> - The Graphics object's *font* is set to the component's `font` property.
> - The Graphics object's *translation* is set such that the coordinate (0,0) represents the upper left corner of the component.
> - The Graphics object's *clip rectangle* is set to the area of the component that is in need of repainting.

To test this, try printing out `g.getClip` :-)

I'll give you a hint...

> ```
> java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=10,height=10]
> java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=10,height=10]
> java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=10,height=10]
> ```

Here's a fixed `moveSquare`...

```
public void moveSquare(int newX, int newY){
  if (newY != y|| newX != x) {
    y = newY;
    x = newX;
    repaint();
  }        
}
```